# .net 5 not showing in Visual Studio 2019 and gives repair errors

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I downloaded and installed .net 5 sdk but it does not show up in Visual Studio Community 2019 v16.8.2 on Windows 10 x64.
If I try to repair the the .net 5 installation it fails with these errors in the log.

[99B4:14D0][2020-11-29T13:17:43]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to run maintanance mode for MSI package.

[99B4:14D0][2020-11-29T13:17:43]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.

[6D24:5D98][2020-11-29T13:17:43]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.

[6D24:5D98][2020-11-29T13:17:43]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.

Here is what I have tried, some of this I got from old support threads:

1. Uninstalling and reinstalling .net 5.  The first time it always says it installed correctly but will not show in VSC 2019.  If I then run repair on .net 5 it fails with the above errors
2. Deleting the files in my temp folder before reinstalling .net 5
3. Deleting the .net 5 directory before reinstalling
4. Repairing my Visual Studio 2019 installation
5. Running the .net repair tool from the microsoft website
6. Checking my Windows 10 Pro installation for errors using  sfc /scannow
7. Uninstalling all old versions of .net through the control panel and then reinstalling .net 5
8. Downloading a second fresh copy of the .net 5 installer

Comment: Are you installing SDK separately? If yest then try use `Visual Studio Installer` and `Modify` option.

Comment: ".net 5 not showing in Visual Studio 2019" What does it mean? Not shown in `Target Framework`? Or not shown in `New project dialog`? If the latter one, after intalling`.NET5`, you can select the template `WPF/Winforms(.NET)` in `New project dialog`, and then you can modifty its target framework in `Project->Porperties->Application`.